# Compare document pairs within corpus using TF-IDF - Python

Tags: python, pandas, tf-idf

I managed to calculate the TF-IDF and matrix using the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#define vectorizer parameters
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.2, stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,3))

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(paragraphs) #fit the vectorizer to paragraphs
```

However, I would now like to compare the similarity of different paragraphs, my end result should look like this:

```
Pair# | Paragraph1 | Paragraph2 | Similarity score

1 --------xyz --------xyz --------- 30.2%

2 --------xyz --------xyz --------- 22.3%

3  --------xyz --------xyz --------- 4.3%
```

How can I use the `TF-IDF` matrix to compare the different paragraph pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each paragraph in your `paragraphs` parameter is a string, then each row in your `tfidf_matrix` would be a numeric vector representing that string. A common metric for measuring the similarity between vectors (and specifically tf-idf weight vectors) is [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). One useful implementation is the [scikit-learn cosine_similarity method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)  which accepts matrices as inputs.

So presumably you could do:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_sim_matrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

Every cell `i, j` will be the similarity score between paragraphs `i` and `j`.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the `cosine_sim_matrix` to a single numeric score between zero and one?

Comment: That really depends on your motivation. Each cell of ````cosine_sim_matrix```` is a value between 0 and 1. You could maybe just take the average of all the cells via ````cosine_sim_matrix.reshape(-1).mean()```` and get a single value between 0 and 1. It's up to you wether that makes sense or not.